# How can I iterate an object using ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am facing problem in iterating an object,in which i have pushed the same property(value) from array of objects.

```
    {
     id:1,
     id:2,
     id:3
    }
```

I want to display these id's in different rows of table like:
          1
          2
          3

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: will the key be id for all the properties of the object?

Comment: Do you have anything else in array to show in table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller("mycontroller", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        "id": 1        
      }
      ,{
        "id": 2
      }
      ,{
        "id": 3
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller" class="container">
  <h4>My items</h4>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items ">{{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't have the same key repeated in an object.
Assuming you have an array of objects called 'idObjects': [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}], you can use ng-repeat on the tr element like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="idObj in idObjects">
    <td>{{ idObj.id }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = { id:1, id:2, id:3 };
var $scope.objToArr = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  $scope.objToArr.push(value);
});
```

in your html

```
<tr ng-repeat="idval in objToArr">
    <td>{{ idval}}</td>
  </tr>
```

it works even for different keys also.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the json object into an array and assign it to a `$scope` variable and then use `ng-repeat` to iterate over the array.

Controller code:

```
var jsonObj = { "id1":1, "id2": 2, "id3": 3 }; // your object

// constructing the array with your object;
$scope.idArray = Object.keys(jsonObj).map(function(k) { return jsonObj[k] });
```

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="id in idArray track by $index">
        <td>{{ id }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: thanks for your help.It works for me,but i have one doubt could you plz help me

Comment: @rama Yes sure. What is it?

Comment: actually i have <tr> with 3 td's in table ,for first 2 td's i have given ng-repeat in <tr>,but  for third td i have to take seperate ng-repeat is it possible

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You need to have a single `ng-repeat`to avoid repetitions or duplicates. But you can construct an array with the data required for the first two `<td>`'s and also third `<td>` and have an `ng-repeat`. This is definitely possible

Comment: for that td i have to get those id's,but when i am directly giving ng-repeat to that td it is generating one more column and i also tried by using span but it is displaying all the object properties in same line..can you please help me

Comment: @rama Please update your question with whatever functionality you want and the required data objects. We can help you.